# How to show random items in an array of 6 items ReactJS and React Hook and reshuffle the array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Currently building hanging man game and in my case there is an array which contains 6 items. So in one round every item will be shown once of course, and also keep in mind that it is not possible to show the duplicated items in the same round. Below I was attempting to write the code that do the job, unfortunately this is not working in my case. The problem with my code is that it will keep looping through the array and when it comes to the latest index it should shuffle the array. But I get the error word is undefined if the

> function shuffle

is being called

```js
   let data = ['apple', 'boring', 'citrus', 'dopamine', 'earth'];
   
   const randomWord = () => {
        setArrayCount(arrayCount + 1);
        console.log(arrayCount, data.length);
        if(arrayCount > data.length) {
            setArrayCount(0);
            shuffle(data);
        } else {

        }

        replaceLetter(data[arrayCount].word);
        cleanWord();
    }

    const shuffle = (a) => {
        // create copy or new array
        let newArr = [].concat(a);
        for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [newArr[i], newArr[j]] = [newArr[j], newArr[i]];
        }
        console.log(newArr);
        return newArr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@frontend. Please see my code:

```
const App = () => {
  let data = ["apple", "boring", "citrus", "dopamine", "earth"];
  const [wordArray, setWordArray] = useState([]);
  const clearData = () => {
    setWordArray([]);
    return ["apple", "boring", "citrus", "dopamine", "earth"]
  }
  const randomElem = data => {
    while (data.length > 0) {
      const indexChoose = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
      wordArray.push(data[indexChoose]);
      setWordArray(wordArray);
      data.splice(indexChoose, 1);
    }
    data = clearData()
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          randomElem(data); 
          console.log('result: ',wordArray);
        }}
      >
        Change
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          clearData(); 
          console.log('result: ',wordArray);
        }}
      >
        Clear
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```